# JSON output to the browser -> providing an order

Tags: json, api

So I've read that you cannot expect a default order when requesting json. I've seen this in action making a call to a little api that I built, that will return a jumbled, random order of elements each time I make a different call.

How does a site like ticketfly's api ( call it here http://www.ticketfly.com/api/events/upcoming.json?venueId=57 ) always ensure that the json returned is in a specific order?

The event ids always first, etc.

Thanks for shedding some light on the situation.

Answer (score 1):

If you are in control of the endpoint API then you can hardcode the order in which you render the properties. Though I have to ask why exactly do you need the JSON properties in a particular order? You will finally be accessing the properties via there property names so the order in which they appear in the JSON should not ideally matter.

**EDIT :** Since your bosses insist on this (what can one say now?):

You can try and see if any of the following suits your needs:

1. Try hardcoding the *display order* in the view's representation. This means you will need to echo/print each property name explicitly in the view script. In PHP it could be something like `echo $variable_representing_json["id"];` and so forth. Note that with this approach you needn't change the original JSON representation.
2. If you want the original JSON representation to be changed then depending on how you are doing the process it varies in difficulty:

   - If it's string concatenation that you are using to represent the json then hard-code the order in which the json properties get concatenated in the string.
   - In some languages the display order of properties is actually a representation of the order in which the properties were defined. In simple words if `$var` is an empty json representation then you should define `$var["id"] = {some_val}` first to display it first.
   - If you are using a framework for processing the JSON data it may have its own quirks irrespective of how you define your representation. In such cases you will have to try and see if you can work around the issue or if it gives any helper methods.

Comment: It was a request by my boss- which I imagine is a request by his bosses, since we implemented a viewable representation of the json data (to demonstrate what the api would return). How would I go about hardcoding the properties?